# Create a copy of production databases, without any data?

Tags: sql-server

I need to create a copy of all of our production databases (SQLServer), without any data.
I need to do this on a regular basis, preferably scheduled and not manually.

Do I have to write code that extracts from systables and builds whe SQL-statements itself or is there a good way to do this?

Comment: it might it will help you. http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1070/simple-script-to-backup-all-sql-server-databases/

Comment: Thank's but I can't backup the data - I want the object definitions only.

Comment: ok.then you may create sql script for you database as both schema and data con taint.

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand. It seems I will have to use SMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is a method to do that in SQL Management Studio:

- Select a database
- right click
- tasks
- generate script
- etc ...

You can then save the script generated as an sql file.

Once the script set, and if it is T-SQL, you can just add it to the jobs of your server. .And if you have only a SQL EXPRESS server (with no job schedule), I remember it was possible, a few years ago, to find some free products on the net that would do the job.

Comment: Thank's but I want to be able to schedule this. we can't go through all databases manually every time. How is this done programmatically?

Comment: Sorry, but I need to generate the create-scripts regularly.

Comment: Sorry, but I need to regenerate the create-scripts regularly. Running the create-scripts is no problem, it's the creation of the create-scripts automatically on a regular basis that is my problem.. I guess one can write something with Prowershell and SMO, but I have no experience in that so I unless I find something that works out-of-the-box, I would rather no go down that path, unless it's the only way..

Comment: nothing out of the box. you'll have to go through this one I guess: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.database.script.aspx

Comment: OK, thanks for the link! Everything points to SMO, so I guess I will have to learn this!